# hiding div after another is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide the current div that's displayed using *.toggle* when another is clicked.

When another div is toggled by clicking on another link in *.left*, I want the div that's currently displayed in *.right* to disappear and be replaced with the one that's clicked. Currently div's that have been toggled stay there until toggled off *onclick*, I want the toggle off to trigger when another div is selected from *.left*

Tried using *.hide* and an if statement, but couldn't seem to get the JS to function properly. If someone could just point me in the right direction that would be great.

Apologies if I've phrased this badly (new to SO). Happy to edit accordingly.

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xt1d887/)

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">

  <div class="left">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="links">
        <a href="#">When this link is clicked, i want the first div to be shown</a>
        <a href="#">When this link is clicked, i want the second div to be shown</a>
        <a href="#">When this link is clicked, i want the third div to be shown</a>
        <a href="#">When this link is clicked, i want the fourth div to be shown</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--left-->

  <div class="right">
    <div class="row">
      <div>Content to be shown when the first link is clicked</div>
      <div>Content to be shown when the second link is clicked</div>
      <div>Content to be shown when the third link is clicked</div>
      <div>Content to be shown when the fourth link is clicked</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--right-->

</div><!--wrap-->
```

CSS:

```
.links a {
  display: block;
}

.row > div:not(.links) {
  display: none;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.left {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.right {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}

.links a {
  width: 490px;
}

.links {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
var links = $('.links a');
links.on('click', function() {
  var n = links.index(this);
  $('.row > div:not(.links)').eq(n).toggle();
});
```

Comment: take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7xt1d887/3/)

Comment: Hide `$('.row > div:not(.links)')` then show `$('.row > div:not(.links)').eq(n)` each time rather than toggling should do the trick if I'm understanding the question correctly.

Comment: Have you searched on SO for other solutions?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it can be done with the same selector too: `$('.row > div:not(.links)').hide().eq(n).toggle();` (eq is called after hide, so all elements are hidden first) https://jsfiddle.net/7xt1d887/2/

Comment: @Rob Yes, I looked for a while, also trawled the JQuery api library, counldnt find anything specific (still learning JS). Apologies if this has existed on SO before.

Comment: @DBS Thanks! Exactly what I needed. I think i was just looking down the wrong avenue. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your code inside the `function`

```
 $('.row > div:not(.links)').hide();
```

Here is [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4Lkpfd2/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this i little edit your code see live demo at https://jsfiddle.net/7xt1d887/ Hope it will help You :)

ADD this

```
$('.right .row').find('div').hide();
```